# What does require('module')(parameter); mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js what does what does `var module = require('module')(parameter);` mean?

Is it the same as:

```
var module = require('module');
mod = module(parameter);
```

Comment: Yes, it's the same. `require()` is a function that returns a value, so that value can be used just like the return value from any other function. If the return value is a function, then it can be used like a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as :

```
var mod = require('module'),
    module = mod(parameter);
```

That's just mean that `require('module')` returns a function. `require(...)` can returns anything, it can be an object, a string, a function, anything.